Как преобразовать список
Если список в таком формате:
{
  "~ZA": "чемпионат 1"
(
  "AE": "команда 1",
  "AF": "команда 2",
)
(
  "AE": "команда 3",
  "AF": "команда 4",
)
}

{
  "~ZA": "чемпионат 2"
(
  "AE": "команда 1",
  "AF": "команда 2",
)
(
  "AE": "команда 3",
  "AF": "команда 4",
)
(
  "AE": "команда 5",
  "AF": "команда 6",
)
}

Подскажите как преобразовать его в такой вид:
"чемпионат 1","команда 1","команда 2";
"чемпионат 1","команда 3","команда 4";
"чемпионат 2","команда 1","команда 2";
"чемпионат 2","команда 3","команда 4";
"чемпионат 2","команда 5","команда 6";


Такого формата НЕ существует в Питоне. Сформируйте данные приемлемо, так, чтоб это был исполняемый код в Питоне, и ответ будет очевиден. Если это содержимое текстового файла, то это содержимое, а не "формат". Я б задумался даже и о формате содержимого файла. К чему он в таком виде?

Если додумать формат, то можно так:
data = [
    {"~ZA": "чемпионат 1", "matches": [("команда 1", "команда 2"), ("команда 3", "команда 4")]},
    {"~ZA": "чемпионат 2", "matches": [("команда 1", "команда 2"), ("команда 3", "команда 4"), ("команда 5", "команда 6")]}
]

result = ';\n'.join([f'"{item["~ZA"]}","{team1}","{team2}"' for item in data for team1, team2 in item["matches"]])+";"

print(result)

Вывод
"чемпионат 1","команда 1","команда 2";
"чемпионат 1","команда 3","команда 4";
"чемпионат 2","команда 1","команда 2";
"чемпионат 2","команда 3","команда 4";
"чемпионат 2","команда 5","команда 6";


Спасибо, то что нужно
